How do I stop text fields inside a table from deselecting when being edited?
I am creating a table listing survey questions when creating a survey for an HR web application. One of the planned features is for the user to be able to modify the text of a question that has already been added. I am importing most of the components being used from MUI. The code is shown below
import TableContainer from "@mui/material/TableContainer";
import Table from "@mui/material/Table";
import TableBody from "@mui/material/TableBody";
import TableRow from "@mui/material/TableRow";
import TableCell from "@mui/material/TableCell";
import TextField from "@mui/material/TextField";
import { styled } from "@mui/system";
import { useState } from "react";

export default function TableTextFieldTest() {
    const [questions, setQuestions] = useState([
        {
            index: 0,
            question: "Do you have any feedback on your manager or team that you'd like to share?",
        },
        {
            index: 1,
            question: "What suggestions do you have for improving the company culture or work environment?",
        },
        {   
            index: 2,
            question: "How was your experience working here?",
        }
    ]);

    //Custom style elements
    const TableBodyCell = styled(TableCell)({
        paddingLeft: "24px",
        paddingRight: "24px",
        paddingTop: "16px",
        paddingBottom: "16px"
    });

    //Handle changes to the textfield when editing a survey question
    function handleEditTextfield(e, index) {
        const newQuestions = Array.from(questions);
        const q = newQuestions.find((q) => q.index === index);
        q.question = e.target.value;
        setQuestions(newQuestions);
    };

    return (
        <TableContainer>
            <Table>
                <TableBody>
                    {questions.sort((q1, q2) => q1.index - q2.index).map((q, index) => (
                        <TableRow>
                            <TableBodyCell>
                                <TextField 
                                    value={q.question}
                                    onChange={(e) => handleEditTextfield(e, index)}
                                    sx={{ width: "100%" }}
                                />
                            </TableBodyCell>
                        </TableRow>
                    ))}
                </TableBody>
            </Table>
        </TableContainer>
    );
};


One of the problems I'm having is that the textfield keeps losing focus after each change. It appears that this happens whenever the textfield is rendered inside a table. Is there a way to maintain the focus on the textfield that is being modified?

I believe the text field is losing focus because the entire table is being re-rendered when the state updates. I’ve updated the code below, adding a key to maintain focus and optimising the state update:
import TableContainer from "@mui/material/TableContainer";
import Table from "@mui/material/Table";
import TableBody from "@mui/material/TableBody";
import TableRow from "@mui/material/TableRow";
import TableCell from "@mui/material/TableCell";
import TextField from "@mui/material/TextField";
import { styled } from "@mui/system";
import { useState } from "react";

export default function TableTextFieldTest() {
    const [questions, setQuestions] = useState([
        {
            index: 0,
            question: "Do you have any feedback on your manager or team that you'd like to share?",
        },
        {
            index: 1,
            question: "What suggestions do you have for improving the company culture or work environment?",
        },
        {   
            index: 2,
            question: "How was your experience working here?",
        }
    ]);

    const TableBodyCell = styled(TableCell)({
        paddingLeft: "24px",
        paddingRight: "24px",
        paddingTop: "16px",
        paddingBottom: "16px"
    });

    function handleEditTextfield(e, index) {
        setQuestions(prevQuestions => 
            prevQuestions.map(q => 
                q.index === index ? { ...q, question: e.target.value } : q
            )
        );
    };

    return (
        <TableContainer>
            <Table>
                <TableBody>
                    {questions
                        .sort((q1, q2) => q1.index - q2.index)
                        .map((q) => (
                            <TableRow key={q.index}>
                                <TableBodyCell>
                                    <TextField 
                                        value={q.question}
                                        onChange={(e) => handleEditTextfield(e, q.index)}
                                        sx={{ width: "100%" }}
                                    />
                                </TableBodyCell>
                            </TableRow>
                    ))}
                </TableBody>
            </Table>
        </TableContainer>
    );
};

Changes made are:

Added a key prop to the TableRow component using q.index
Modified handleEditTextfield to use the functional update pattern with prevQuestions
Changed the index parameter in handleEditTextfield to use q.index instead of the map index
Used proper array immutability patterns in the state update

The above changes should maintain focus on the text field while editing. The problems with the original code were:

Missing key props, which caused React to re-mount components unnecessarily
Using Array.from() and find() which created new references and triggered unnecessary re-renders
Using the map index instead of the question index, which could cause issues if questions were reordered

This should, hopefully, resolve the issue.
EDIT I:
Here’s a different approach using a controlled editing state:
import TableContainer from "@mui/material/TableContainer";
import Table from "@mui/material/Table";
import TableBody from "@mui/material/TableBody";
import TableRow from "@mui/material/TableRow";
import TableCell from "@mui/material/TableCell";
import TextField from "@mui/material/TextField";
import { styled } from "@mui/system";
import { useState, useRef } from "react";

export default function TableTextFieldTest() {
    const [questions, setQuestions] = useState([
        {
            index: 0,
            question: "Do you have any feedback on your manager or team that you'd like to share?",
        },
        {
            index: 1,
            question: "What suggestions do you have for improving the company culture or work environment?",
        },
        {   
            index: 2,
            question: "How was your experience working here?",
        }
    ]);
    
    // Track which question is being edited
    const [editingIndex, setEditingIndex] = useState(null);
    // Store the current value while editing
    const [editingValue, setEditingValue] = useState("");

    const TableBodyCell = styled(TableCell)({
        paddingLeft: "24px",
        paddingRight: "24px",
        paddingTop: "16px",
        paddingBottom: "16px"
    });

    const handleStartEditing = (index, initialValue) => {
        setEditingIndex(index);
        setEditingValue(initialValue);
    };

    const handleEditTextfield = (e) => {
        setEditingValue(e.target.value);
        // Update the questions array
        setQuestions(prevQuestions =>
            prevQuestions.map(q =>
                q.index === editingIndex ? { ...q, question: e.target.value } : q
            )
        );
    };

    return (
        <TableContainer>
            <Table>
                <TableBody>
                    {questions
                        .sort((q1, q2) => q1.index - q2.index)
                        .map((q) => (
                            <TableRow key={q.index}>
                                <TableBodyCell>
                                    <TextField 
                                        value={editingIndex === q.index ? editingValue : q.question}
                                        onChange={handleEditTextfield}
                                        onFocus={() => handleStartEditing(q.index, q.question)}
                                        sx={{ width: "100%" }}
                                    />
                                </TableBodyCell>
                            </TableRow>
                    ))}
                </TableBody>
            </Table>
        </TableContainer>
    );
};


Added editingIndex state to track which question is currently being edited
Added editingValue state to maintain the current value while editing
Added handleStartEditing function that's called when a TextField gets focus
Modified the TextField to use either the editing value or the stored question value depending on whether it's being edited

This approach should maintain focus while editing because:

The TextField's value is controlled by the editingValue state when being edited
We're tracking which field is being edited separately from the questions array
The focus/blur cycle is managed explicitly

If this approach still doesn't work, you might need to try a different approach with contentEditable or a custom input component.
EDIT II:
Tables can be tricky with input fields in React, because they have strict rules with what elements can be nested inside table cells, and they often trigger re-renders in unexpected ways. The focus loss issue happens because:

Tables in React (and HTML in general) require a specific DOM structure
Material-UI's Table components add additional wrapper elements and event handlers
State updates can cause the entire table to re-render, which can disrupt focus

Try these alternative approaches:
Use divs styled as a table instead:
function TableTextFieldTest() {
    const [questions, setQuestions] = useState([/* your questions */]);

    const TableLikeContainer = styled('div')({
        display: 'table',
        width: '100%'
    });
    
    const TableLikeRow = styled('div')({
        display: 'table-row'
    });
    
    const TableLikeCell = styled('div')({
        display: 'table-cell',
        padding: '16px 24px'
    });

    return (
        <TableLikeContainer>
            {questions.map((q) => (
                <TableLikeRow key={q.index}>
                    <TableLikeCell>
                        <TextField 
                            value={q.question}
                            onChange={(e) => handleEditTextfield(e, q.index)}
                            sx={{ width: "100%" }}
                        />
                    </TableLikeCell>
                </TableLikeRow>
            ))}
        </TableLikeContainer>
    );
}

Use a Grid or Stack component instead:
import { Stack } from '@mui/material';

function TableTextFieldTest() {
    const [questions, setQuestions] = useState([/* your questions */]);

    return (
        <Stack spacing={2} sx={{ width: '100%' }}>
            {questions.map((q) => (
                <TextField 
                    key={q.index}
                    value={q.question}
                    onChange={(e) => handleEditTextfield(e, q.index)}
                    sx={{ width: "100%" }}
                />
            ))}
        </Stack>
    );
}

If you must use a table, you could try wrapping the TextField in a div:
<TableCell>
    <div style={{ width: '100%' }}>
        <TextField 
            value={q.question}
            onChange={(e) => handleEditTextfield(e, q.index)}
            sx={{ width: "100%" }}
        />
    </div>
</TableCell>

I'd recommend trying the first or second approach since they'll likely be more stable. The Grid/Stack approach in particular is a more modern way to handle layouts in Material-UI and tends to have fewer quirks than tables.

I'm sorry, but this didn't work. I copied your whole code segment into my script and I'm still having the same problem

I edited the answer to address this issue. Try it and see if it works this time.

Unfortunately, this didn't work either. This seems to only happen whenever a textfield is inside a table. What is it about tables that causes this problem?

I've added a few more alternative approaches. It should work this time

You can use the useRef hook to store the reference to each text field this is how React will update the component's state.
For your reference you can see this
const inputRefs = useRef([]);

   const handleFocus = (index) => {
        if (inputRefs.current[index]) {
            inputRefs.current[index].focus();
        }
    };

// and In Render
<TextField
value={q.question}
onChange={(e) => handleEditTextfield(e, index)}
onFocus={() => handleFocus(index)}
sx={{ width: "100%" }}
/>


Using the useRef hook doesn't help.
